# Can two different time series be compared in prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator, prometheus-net

I would like compare the following two time series which are different from each other. All I want to do is divide the result of the ***Second time series*** by the result of the ***First time series*** and generate an alert if the value is less than 1. The query that I am using is below the time series that I have mentioned below. How to achieve my goal?

***First time series:***

container_memory_usage_bytes{container_name="documentation"}

**RESULT:**

```
container_memory_usage_bytes{
   beta_kubernetes_io_arch="amd64",
   beta_kubernetes_io_fluentd_ds_ready="true",
   beta_kubernetes_io_instance_type="n1-highmem-8",
   beta_kubernetes_io_os="linux",
   cloud_google_com_gke_nodepool="pool-1",
   container_name="documentation",
   failure_domain_beta_kubernetes_io_region="europe-west1",
   failure_domain_beta_kubernetes_io_zone="europe-west1-b",
   id="/kubepods/burstable/podb79239ff-1ee9-11e8-a6c1-42010a840fd9/3ccdaa6597d5bd306d228e37d9d4c65a9681dba2e894aa7b7ed4502ec54e5619",
   image="gcr.io/ingenious-169318/publicapi/documentation@sha256:60a5454bb40ed34f24cbeb9f330e1097191754cf2890eee1ca4f2988188a7705",
   instance="gke-ingenious-pool-1-bbd77706-5rbz",
   job="kubernetes-cadvisor",
   kubernetes_io_hostname="gke-ingenious-pool-1-bbd77706-5rbz",
   name="k8s_documentation_documentation-6c4c4c9f5f-dn2bv_apimanager_b79239ff-1ee9-11e8-a6c1-42010a840fd9_0",
   namespace="apimanager",
   pod_name="documentation-6c4c4c9f5f-dn2bv"
}
```

***Second time series:-***

kube_pod_container_resource_requests_memory_bytes{container="documentation"}

**RESULT:**

```
kube_pod_container_resource_requests_memory_bytes{
   container="documentation",
   instance="10.32.0.30:8080",
   job="kubernetes-service-endpoints",
   k8s_app="kube-state-metrics",
   kubernetes_name="kube-state-metrics",
   kubernetes_namespace="kube-system",
   namespace="apimanager",
   node="gke-ingenious-pool-1-bbd77706-pdsz",
   pod="documentation-6c4c4c9f5f-mzd54"
}
```

***PromQL:***

kube_pod_container_resource_requests_memory_bytes{container="documentation"} / (container_memory_usage_bytes{namespace="apimanager"})

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Vector Matching**

Prometheus calls this [Vector Matching](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching), you can perform arithmetic binary operations (+, -, *, / etc) across different time series if their labels match. If they don't match you can using `on` or `ignoring` to chose which labels you should match on.

> One-to-one finds a unique pair of entries from each side of the
>   operation. In the default case, that is an operation following the
>   format vector1  vector2. Two entries match if they have the
>   exact same set of labels and corresponding values. The ignoring
>   keyword allows ignoring certain labels when matching, while the on
>   keyword allows reducing the set of considered labels to a provided
>   list

e.g.

```
kube_pod_container_resource_requests_memory_bytes{container="documentation"}
/ on (container)
container_memory_usage_bytes{namespace="apimanager"}
```

**label_join/label_replace**

Looking at your specific example there aren't any labels that you could use `on` to match with. `container_memory_usage_bytes` has `container_name` while `kube_pod_container_resource_requests_memory_bytes` has `container`. Prometheus has other query functions called [label_join](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_join) and [label_replace](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace) which allow you to create custom labels on one of your metrics.

In your case you might want to use label_replace to append `_name` to `kube_pod_container_resource_requests_memory_bytes`. Which would then allow you to use `/ on (container_name)` as shown above.

Hopefully these 2 prometheus concepts, vector matching and label_join/replace will help you perform arithmetic operations across disparate time series. NB I'm not familiar enough with your exact use case to know if `container_name` is the best label to use to achieve your required output or if there is a simpler way of achieving this with Kubernetes and Prometheus.